# Definite integral of Planck's law

Tags: integration

I want to be able to solve the following,
\begin{equation}
   \frac{\int_{0}^{\lambda_0} B(\lambda, T)\,d\lambda} {\int_{0}^{\infty} B(\lambda,T)\,d\lambda} 
\end{equation}

where $B(\lambda,T)$ represents Planck's law:
\begin{equation}\label{planck}
   B(\lambda,T) = \frac{2 h c^2}{\lambda^5} \frac{1}{\exp{\frac{hc}{\lambda k_B T}} - 1}
\end{equation}

The integral of the denominator results in the Stefan Boltzmann law; however, how would I be able to compute the definite integral in the numerator?

Comment: [Numerically?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+1%2F%28x%5E5%28exp%281%2Fx%29-1%29%29+from+x%3D0+to+0.4)

Comment: To what neat analytical expression are you referring? If you define a dimensionless variable x which is proportional to the wavelength, then the integral you’d be solving numerically would look like that.

Comment: @J.Murray Yes I apologize for that. Thank you, it makes perfect sense!

Comment: This belongs in Math SE.

Answer (score 0):

With CAS help I have:

$$\int_0^{\text{$\lambda $0}} \frac{2 h c^2}{\lambda ^5 \left(\exp \left(\frac{h c}{\lambda  \text{kB}
   T}\right)-1\right)} \, d\lambda =\\\int_0^{\text{$\lambda $0}} \frac{\left(2 h c^2\right) \sum _{j=1}^{\infty }
   \exp \left(-\frac{j (h c)}{\lambda  \text{kB} T}\right)}{\lambda ^5} \, d\lambda =\\\sum _{j=1}^{\infty }
   \int_0^{\text{$\lambda $0}} \frac{\left(2 h c^2\right) \exp \left(-\frac{j (h c)}{\lambda  \text{kB}
   T}\right)}{\lambda ^5} \, d\lambda =\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{2 e^{-\frac{c h j}{\text{kB} T \text{$\lambda
   $0}}} \text{kB} T \left(c^3 h^3 j^3+3 c^2 h^2 j^2 \text{kB} T \text{$\lambda $0}+6 c h j \text{kB}^2 T^2
   \text{$\lambda $0}^2+6 \text{kB}^3 T^3 \text{$\lambda $0}^3\right)}{c^2 h^3 j^4 \text{$\lambda $0}^3}=-\frac{2
   c \text{kB} T \ln \left(1-e^{-\frac{c h}{\text{kB} T \text{$\lambda $0}}}\right)}{\text{$\lambda
   $0}^3}+\frac{6 \text{kB}^2 T^2 \text{Li}_2\left(e^{-\frac{c h}{\text{kB} T \text{$\lambda $0}}}\right)}{h
   \text{$\lambda $0}^2}+\frac{12 \text{kB}^3 T^3 \text{Li}_3\left(e^{-\frac{c h}{\text{kB} T \text{$\lambda
   $0}}}\right)}{c h^2 \text{$\lambda $0}}+\frac{12 \text{kB}^4 T^4 \text{Li}_4\left(e^{-\frac{c h}{\text{kB} T
   \text{$\lambda $0}}}\right)}{c^2 h^3}$$

Mathematica code:

`Integrate[(2 h c^2)/\[Lambda]^5*1/( Exp[(h c)/(\[Lambda] kB T)] - 1), {\[Lambda],  0, \[Lambda]0}] == -(( 2 c kB T Log[1 - E^(-((c h)/(kB T \[Lambda]0)))])/\[Lambda]0^3) + ( 6 kB^2 T^2 PolyLog[2, E^(-((c h)/(kB T \[Lambda]0)))])/( h \[Lambda]0^2) + ( 12 kB^3 T^3 PolyLog[3, E^(-((c h)/(kB T \[Lambda]0)))])/( c h^2 \[Lambda]0) + ( 12 kB^4 T^4 PolyLog[4, E^(-((c h)/(kB T \[Lambda]0)))])/(c^2 h^3)`